# SELinux Contexts

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, selinux

I am configuring Apache\PHP and noticed Apache complaining about permissions with the php shared object.

```
Starting httpd: 
httpd: Syntax error on line 206 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: 
Cannot load /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so into server: 
/usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so: cannot restore segment prot after reloc: 
Permission denied
```

I looked at the context (started fine with enforcement off) and found:

```
# ls --context /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
-rwxr-xr-x root root root:object_r:httpd_modules_t /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
```

Shouldn't httpd (apache) be able to access files with a context of `httpd_modules_t`? I got it fixed by applying

```
chcon -t textrel_shlib_t '/usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so'
```

But I would think the httpd version would work before this one. Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 4):

Under SELinux each item is required to have a context. Text relocation can be described as an error. Changing the context creates an exception coaxing SELinux into allowing it to load even though it in essence is b0rken. Way better text relocation explanation: http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/textrelocs.html. BTW using `chcon` isn't permanent: relabelling will reset the context. Use

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t textrel_shlib_t /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
```

to make it stick (see `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.local`).

HTH